# Yeoman Gruntfile dist task Not copying styles from .tmp folder (AngularJs)

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator

For some reason my Angular grunt task is not copying the stylesheets from the .tmp folder when I run "grunt". "Grunt server" works fine.

I've been staring at this for quite some time and have tried a couple different things, however it's not working for me, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
// Generated on 2013-11-05 using generator-angular 0.5.1
'use strict';
var LIVERELOAD_PORT = 35729;
var mountFolder = function (connect, dir) {
    return connect.static(require('path').resolve(dir));
};

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    // configurable paths
    var yeomanConfig = {
        app: 'app',
        dist: 'dist'
    };

    try {
        yeomanConfig.app = require('./bower.json').appPath || yeomanConfig.app;
    } catch (e) {}

    grunt.initConfig({
        yeoman: yeomanConfig,
        watch: {
            // coffee: {
            //   files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.coffee'],
            //   tasks: ['coffee:dist']
            // },
            // coffeeTest: {
            //   files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.coffee'],
            //   tasks: ['coffee:test']
            // },
            compass: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
                tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
            },
            styles: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
                tasks: ['copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    livereload: LIVERELOAD_PORT
                },
                files: [
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
                    '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
                ]
            }
        },
        autoprefixer: {
            options: ['last 1 version'],
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                    src: '{,*/}*.css',
                    dest: '.tmp/styles/'
                }]
            }
        },
        connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
                hostname: 'localhost'
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                            mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.app)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            test: {
                options: {
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                            mountFolder(connect, 'test')
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.dist)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        open: {
            server: {
                url: 'http://localhost:<%= connect.options.port %>'
            }
        },
        clean: {
     options: { force: true },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    dot: true,
                    src: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
                        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            server: '.tmp'
        },
    // jshint: {
        //   options: {
        //       jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
        //   },
        //   all: [
        //       'Gruntfile.js',
        //       '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
        //   ]
        // },
        // coffee: {
        //   options: {
        //       sourceMap: true,
        //       sourceRoot: ''
        //   },
        //   dist: {
        //       files: [{
        //           expand: true,
        //           cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
        //           src: '{,*/}*.coffee',
        //           dest: '.tmp/scripts',
        //           ext: '.js'
        //       }]
        //   },
        //   test: {
        //       files: [{
        //           expand: true,
        //           cwd: 'test/spec',
        //           src: '{,*/}*.coffee',
        //           dest: '.tmp/spec',
        //           ext: '.js'
        //       }]
        //   }
        // },
        compass: {
            options: {
                sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
                cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
                generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
                imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
                fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/fonts',
                importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
                httpImagesPath: '/images',
                httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
                httpFontsPath: '/fonts',
                relativeAssets: false
            },
            dist: {},
            server: {
                options: {
                    debugInfo: true
                }
            }
        },
        // not used since Uglify task does concat,
        // but still available if needed
        /*concat: {
            dist: {}
        },*/
        rev: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    src: [
                        // removed these as the prod server wont like all the new commits
                        // '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                        // '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                        // '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}', HAD TO REMOVE THIS SINCE IT WASN"T REVVING SOME FILES
                        // '<%= yeoman.dist %>/fonts/*'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        useminPrepare: {
            html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
            options: {
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            }
        },
        usemin: {
            html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
            css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
            options: {
                dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
            }
        },
        imagemin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
                }]
            }
        },
        // svgmin: {
        //   dist: {
        //       files: [{
        //           expand: true,
        //           cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
        //           src: '{,*/}*.svg',
        //           dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        //       }]
        //   }
        // },
        cssmin: {
            // By default, your `index.html` <!-- Usemin Block --> will take care of
            // minification. This option is pre-configured if you do not wish to use
            // Usemin blocks.
            // dist: {
            //   files: {
            //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
            //           '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            //           '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
            //       ]
            //   }
            // }
        },
        htmlmin: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    /*removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                    // https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/44
                    //collapseWhitespace: true,
                    collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                    removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                    removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                    useShortDoctype: true,
                    removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                    removeOptionalTags: true*/
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                    src: ['*.html', 'views/{,*/}{,*/}{,*/}{,*/}{,*/}{,*/}*.html'],
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
                }]
            }
        },
        // Put files not handled in other tasks here
        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                    src: [
                        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                        '.htaccess',
                        'bower_components/**/*',
                        'images/**/*',
                        'scripts/**/*',
                        'staticData/**/*',
                        'fonts/*'
                    ]
                }, {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/images',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
                    src: [
                        'generated/*'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            styles: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
                dest: '.tmp/styles/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css'
            }
        },
        concurrent: {
            server: [
                // 'coffee:dist',
                'compass:server',
                'copy:styles'
            ],
            test: [
                // 'coffee',
                'compass',
                'copy:styles'
            ],
            dist: [
                // 'coffee',
                'compass:dist',
                'copy:styles',
                'imagemin',
                // 'svgmin',
                'htmlmin'
            ]
        },
        // karma: {
        //   unit: {
        //       configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
        //       singleRun: true
        //   }
        // },
        cdnify: {
            dist: {
                html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
            }
        },
        ngmin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts',
                    src: '*.js',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts'
                }]
            }
        },
        uglify: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/app.js': [
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/app.js'
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
        if (target === 'dist') {
            return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'concurrent:server',
            'autoprefixer',
            'connect:livereload',
            'watch'
        ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('test', [
        'clean:server',
        'concurrent:test',
        'autoprefixer',
        'connect:test'
        // 'karma'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        // 'useminPrepare',
        'concurrent:dist',
        'autoprefixer',
        // 'concat',
        'copy:dist',
        'cdnify',
        'ngmin',
        // 'cssmin',
        // 'uglify',
        'rev',
        // 'usemin'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        // 'jshint',
        'test',
        'build'
    ]);
};
```

Comment: The watch task actually runs some tasks of its own when it detects certain changes. When it sees changes to your scss/sass files, it runs compass:server and autoprefixer tasks. Those modify your css files, which causes the watch task to run copy:styles and autoprefixer again. Grunt server runs your watch task - this is why grunt server works. You need to add copy:styles and autoprefixer tasks to the 'build' task.

Comment: Thanks @MikePugh No dice though :(

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is actually copying them, but it will remove the right after that... The thing is when you call `grunt` it will call `default` task.

So first is the `test` task, which will copy styles via `concurrent:test`

But as soon as `test` is done, `build` is called, and the first thing it does is `clean:dist` which will remove those styles

If you want to have them anyway, you can add `copy:styles` after `copy:dist` in the `build` task

```
grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'copy:dist',
    'copy:styles',
    'cdnify',
    'ngmin',
    'rev'
]);
```

Comment: try to switch `dest` and `src` in the `copy:styles` task, I think you have them the other way

Answer (score 0):

uncommenting the "cssmin" seems to have fixed this issue (for some reason)...

Comment: So you solved this problem by deactivating css min? Or by re-activating it?

Comment: Based on the reply I believe it was reactivating it, can't remember this specific issue so I can't give 100% certainty that this is what it was.

Answer (score 0):

replace all {,*/}* to **/* in your Gruntfile.js if you are having sub-directories  in 'scripts' and 'styles'dir.